# MySql Select Statement (Other Company)

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I am trying to select distinct users that are listed for other companies but not on my company (1). Here is an example

```
Placement User Company
1          1      1
2          1      2
3          2      2
4          3      1
5          2      1
```

From this table, I would like to get row 4 since he is in other company (not 1) but listed on others. I do not want others because they are listed on both my company and others. Anyone can help?

Comment: Please add your best try to your question by using [Edit].

Comment: you can use `select distinct u from User u join Company c on u.id = c.userId where c.id != 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN`. For example:

```
select distinct user 
from t 
where user not in (
  select user from t where company = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the logic that you want:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.user = t.user and t1.company = 1
)
```

This gives you the records for which no other record exists for the same user and company 1.